# SQL like clause is not returning any results

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have following query, but it doesn't return any results for where clauses, even when there is row with that kind of name what is queried. If I remove where clause, then all records in Company table which have OfficeLocation table are returned. What is wrong in my query?

```
SELECT c.* 
FROM        [MyDb].[dbo].[Company] AS c
INNER JOIN  [MyDb].[dbo].[CompanyOfficeLocation] AS col ON c.Id = col.CompanyId
INNER JOIN  [MyDb].[dbo].[OfficeLocation] AS ol ON ol.Id = col.OfficeLocationId
WHERE ol.Name like '%Actual Name In This Table%';
```

Table structure :

```
Company
    Id
    etc ...

CompanyOfficeLocation
    CompanyId
    OfficeLocationId

OfficeLocation
    Id
    etc ...
```

Comment: The query as such seems fine - but without seeing table structure and sample data, this cannot be answered...

Comment: If you want to know sample data, then just assume anything at the OfficeLocation. For example if OfficeLocation Name is 'Location A', and I search with that in where, it returns zero results.

Comment: @newbie - I for one would *assume* the statement to work as is. As it isn't, it really is up to you to provide us with additional information. Especially when asked for. What does following statement return `SELECT * FROM OfficeLocation WHERE Name LIKE '%Location A%'`?

Comment: @Lieven it returns zero results, even when there is Name which contains Location A.

Comment: @newbie - you keep *saying* that but we still have to see your first table structure and sample data.

Comment: @Lieven i guess you would dump customer data to stackoverfolw? Anyway I "solved" this, something was messed up in my test database with real data. I cannot post sample data, because its real customer data ..

Comment: @newbie - No I wouldn't but the data types should not be a problem. Good to know your problem is solved but the problem is not entirely clear to me. In the end, there was *no* *Location A* in your `Officelocation` table?

Comment: @Lieven there was Location A, but joint table was missing joining ids, somehow those were messed up, so there was no relations between those tables. I restored another backup and that was working fine.

Comment: @newbie - Bear with me but in that case, how can the statement `SELECT * FROM OfficeLocation WHERE Name LIKE '%Location A%'` return *no* results?

Comment: @Lieven okey, i didn't read that correctly, that should return results. But I was probably thinking about original query in my question ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things for a record to show up given your query:

1. The OfficeLocation you specified (given the ol.Name value) must have an Id value that is used by a record in the CompanyOfficeLocation table in its OfficeLocationId.
2. The CompanyOfficeLocation record that you got in #1 must have a CompanyId that exists in the Company table.

If any of those two criteria are not met, then no records will show up in your query result. The INNER JOIN is essentially an 'AND' clause. If a record could not be related to at least one INNER JOINed table, then that record will not show up at all.

If you want a record to show up despite not having any related records in the joined tables, you may want to consider using [OUTER JOIN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187518%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)s. A RIGHT JOIN in your case to be exact.

Answer (score 1):

I do not find any mistake however I'd suggest you switch the columns after `ON` when joining to maintain standards.

Instead of - `INNER JOIN  [MyDb].[dbo].[OfficeLocation] AS ol ON ol.Id = col.OfficeLocationId`

Do - `INNER JOIN  [MyDb].[dbo].[OfficeLocation] AS ol ON col.OfficeLocationId = ol.Id`

Comment: The sequence of the columns in an `INNER JOIN` scenario is not relevant - that won't help.